# Space Shuttle Hammerhead Cranes Status

Tags: space-shuttle, launchpad

From the beginning of the the shuttle program up until the mid 1990's, both LC-39 launchpads had a hammerhead crane atop of the Fixed Service Structure which was leftover from the Apollo program. What happened to the cranes following their removal?

Answer (score 4):

Judging by comments in discussion groups, they were scrapped bar one example displayed at the Kennedy Space Center:

https://www.nasa.gov/centers/kennedy/news/pad_39a.html suggests that without costly maintenance, the cranes were *experiencing the corrosive effects of the sea air* and so might well have been in too poor a state of repair to be re-used operationally and cost effectively elsewhere (unless as a museum piece, which did happen to one of them, see below). In that case, it is likely that the other two examples were scrapped.

Links:

https://www.apollomaniacs.com/apollo/museums_ksc_e.htm

> LUT (Launch Umbilical Tower)
>
> At the back of Command module, truncated part of real LUT (Launch Umbilical Tower) is on display. On top of that is the Colby Cranes Manufacturing Company's Hammerhead Crane. Behind that, SkyLab's MDA: Multiple Docking Adapter is also on display.

[image]

http://heroicrelics.org/ksc/lut-segment/index.html

> Two segments of Launch Umbilical Tower 1 (LUT-1) were refurbished and placed on display with LUT-1's hammerhead crane in the Apollo/Saturn V Center, just forward of the Saturn V and Command-Service Module 119 (CSM-119).

> LUT-1 was demolished in 2004; it contained some lead-based paint that was considered an environmental hazard.

http://heroicrelics.org/ksc/lut-segment/dsc08641.jpg.html

http://heroicrelics.org/ksc/lut-segment/dsc09117.jpg.html

[image]

https://www.reddit.com/r/space/comments/1zjdna/380_feet_above_the_base_of_the_mobile_launcher/

> The hammerhead crane itself likely came from Mobile Launcher 1, which was used for the first launch of a Saturn V (Apollo 4), the first manned flight to the moon (Apollo 8) and the first lunar landing (Apollo 11). The crew access arm and white room from this Launch Umbilical Tower are currently on display at the KSC

> The remainder of the Launch Umbilical Tower was placed in storage at the KSC industrial area, and was scrapped in 2004, following an unsuccessful attempt to preserve it as a historical artifact.

> Mobile Launcher 1 became Mobile Launch Platform 3, and ML-3 became MLP-1 during the shuttle conversion. Structural elements (including the 25 ton hammerhead cranes) were reused from ML-3 and ML-2 to construct the Space Shuttle's Fixed Service Structure (FSS)

https://launiusr.wordpress.com/2011/08/22/whatever-happened-to-the-apollosaturn-launch-towers/